# gorm Inheritance causes DuplicateMappingException

Tags: grails, grails-orm

My webapp behaves strangely when a child class is reloaded

```
package test
class Test {

    Integer amount

    //static mapping = {
    //    tablePerHierarchy true
    //    autoImport false
    //}
}
```

and the child class

```
package test
class Test1 extends Test{
    String cardNumber
}
```

new table is created after the parent class is reloaded

[image: new table]

but *grails* console throws error if I reload child class

```
ERROR org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager - Plugin [domainClass:3.0.9] could not reload changes to file [/home/gkiko/workspace/test/grails-app/domain/test/Test1.groovy]: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.internal.SESSION_FACTORY_HOLDER-reloaded': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d22a35c' of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d22a35c': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping test.Test1
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.internal.SESSION_FACTORY_HOLDER-reloaded': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#d22a35c' of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d22a35c': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping test.Test1
.... some more stacktrace
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#d22a35c': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping test.Test1
```

How can I fix the problem?

- Grails Version: 3.0.11
- Groovy Version: 2.4.5
- JVM Version: 1.7.0_91

Answer (score 1):

You should restart your application if you are making any changes to your domain class. Although it is working fine in case you are modifying the parent class, but still the dynamic domain entities creation feature doesn't work perfectly.

Comment: Did you try it? It is the only way to reliably bring domain changes into a Grails app.

Comment: @SteveHole yes I did